# css property applying only ie thats working ie 7.... but not working in ie 8?

Tags: css

```
.sample{
   height:15px;
   width:15px;
   margin:10px;
   padding:10px;
   float:left:

   /*this one apply in ie only */
   border:1px solid #fff;
  # border:2px solid #fff;
  /*this one apply in ie only*/  for ie it treats as 2px.**
}
```

This css is working in ie 7(# border:2px solid #fff) perfect. But its not working ie 8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but this should help:

http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html

Comment: Its working perfect IE 7 and 8. 

.sample{
   height:15px;
   width:15px;
   margin:10px;
   padding:10px;
   float:left:

   /*this one apply in ie only */
   border:1px solid #fff;
  # border:2px solid #fff; /* This one is IE 7 and below */
    border:2px solid red\0/; /* this one is IE 8 */
  /*this one apply in ie only*/  for ie it treats as 2px.**
}

Answer (score 0):

If these are specific styles for IE I would recommended using a conditional stylesheets targeted specifically to the version of IE you are using.

Further information can be found on this [Sitepoint article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments).

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfect IE 7 and 8.

.sample{ 
     height:15px; width:15px; 
     margin:10px; 
     padding:10px; 
     float:left:

```
 border:1px solid #fff; /* For All browser's */  

 /*this one apply in ie only*/ 

   # border:2px solid green;   /* This one is IE 7 and below */ 

   border:2px solid red\0/; /* this one is IE 8 */

/*this one apply in ie only || for ie it treats as 2px.*/
```

}